# Amazon Web Crawler tags issue with python

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have the following problem. I try to crawl Amazon subcategories from his link https://www.amazon.com/workout-clothes/b/ref=nav_shopall_sa_sp_athclg/151-4490025-2599936?ie=UTF8&node=11444071011
I use the function begin_crawl(). How can I extract the subcategories from this link? Look only at the code after this line: subcategories = page.find_all("div", {"class": "mm-column"}). Is there another alternative to extract subcategories from categories?. I've got TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. I attached all the error code.I will appreciate any help.

```html
def begin_crawl():

    with open(settings.start_file, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line or line.startswith("#"):
                continue  # skip blank and commented out lines

            page, html = make_request(line)
            count = 0

            # look for subcategory links on this page
           
            subcategories = page.find_all("div", {"class": "mm-column"})  
            subcategories.extend(page.find_all("ul", {"class": "mm-category-list"}))  
            subcategories.extend(page.find("li"))
            sidebar = page.find("div", "a-col-left")

            if sidebar:
                subcategories.extend(sidebar.findAll("li"))  # left sidebar

            for subcategory in subcategories:
                link = subcategory.find("a")
                if not link:
                    continue
                link = link["href"]
                count += 1
                enqueue_url(link)

            log("Found {} subcategories on {}".format(count, line))
```

The error is

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 106, in <module>
    begin_crawl()  # put a bunch of subcategory URLs into the queue
  File "crawler.py", line 35, in begin_crawl
    subcategories = page.find_all("div", {"class": "mm-column"})  
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct selector for subcategories is

```
.bxc-grid__container a
```

Comment: Where is .bxc-grid__container? On the header section?

Comment: It's in body the widgets that inks to subcategories like golf....just search it in the source

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.